# how to include an image in haml coffeescript file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript, haml

Ok, I'm new to all things HAML and Coffeescript ... so please bear with me ...

Say you have this:

```
%li{data-user_id: @id, class: (if @online then 'online' else 'not-online')}
  %a{href: '#'}
    %span.name= @full_name
```

And you want to include an image next to the `@full_name`, is this how you do it?

```
    %li{data-user_id: @id, class: (if @online then 'online' else 'not-online')}
      %a{href: '#'}
        %span.name= @full_name
        = image_path('layout/small.jpg')
```

a) image doesn't show up

b) the list of people that existed there before I added the image_path, well, they disappear!

But if I remove the `image_path`, then the list of people appears again ...

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT

hm ... if I have this:

```
%li{role: 'presentation', data-user_id: @user_id, class: (if @online then 'online' else 'not-online')}
  %a{role: 'menuitem', href: '#'}
    %span= @full_name
    %i.kind.fa.fa-user
```

then the fontawesome icon shows up ...

but if I try this:

```
%li{data-user_id: @id, class: (if @online then 'online' else 'not-online')}
  %a{href: '#'}
    %span.name= @full_name
    %img('layout/small.jpg')
```

No image shows up. For the record, the image path is accurate.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT 2**

Directory path for image: app/assets/images/layout/small.jpg

**EDIT 3**

Directory path for HAML file: app/javascript/templates/contacts/contact.hamlc

**EDIT 4**

`Indentation error in line 2`

But it highlights javascript_include_tag for some reason ...

```
  %link{:href => "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&subset=latin", :rel => "stylesheet"}/
   %title Blah
   = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'
   = javascript_include_tag 'application', '//cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub.min.js'
   = favicon_link_tag 'favicon.png'
   = csrf_meta_tags
   / HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries
```

**EDIT 5**

For testing purposes, this works:

```
%li{data-user_id: @id, class: (if @online then 'online' else 'not-online')}
  %a{href: '#'}
  %img{:src => "http://i62.tinypic.com/wvd7hk.jpg"}
    %span.name= @full_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
%img("layout/small.jpg")
```

Alternatively, you can also use the older and more verbose form:

```
%img{:src => "layout/small.jpg"}
```

I see that you are using Rails, so you can also try editing your original image_tag to this:

```
=image_tag "layout/small.jpg"
```

You may notice that there is no space between the "=" sign and the "image_tag".

Comment: This should work in the haml file if the path to your image is correct. There is no coffeescript on that line, so I suspected that it was purely a haml issue.

Comment: huh! I tried your older one just now ... and the image doesn't show up but the broken image does show up ...

Comment: so, first one doesn't work, and neither does the third one. But the second one does work sorta ... except the broken image shows up ... which means that my path is clearly wrong ... how do i troubleshoot this?

Comment: Could you post your directory tree from this haml file to the image?

Comment: What is the path to your haml file? I'm assuming it's in app/views/...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77367/discussion-between-alex-pan-and-user27307254534534534543675765).